# Rails 5 - How to include all vendor assets in the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline, vendor

I've found several different threads on including assets in the `vendor/assets` directory but did not find anything that worked for me. Previously, I had all of my vendor assets in the `app/` directory but moved the JavaScript to the `vendor/assets/javascripts/` directory and the CSS to the `vendor/assets/stylesheets/` directory.

I'm now trying to load my vendor assets both in development and production, and they're not loading at all. Here's my `assets.rb` file:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Add additional assets to the asset load path
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [
  Rails.root.join('vendor/assets/javascripts/*').to_s,
  Rails.root.join('vendor/assets/stylesheets/*').to_s
]
```

I've also tried adding the `vendor/assets/` directories to `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`, and that didn't help.

How can I include all of the vendor assets in the asset pipeline?

**UPDATE**

I got my vendor JavaScript to load by adding the following to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
```

However, I'm using Sass and am still not able to get the SCSS files to load.

Comment: Did you restart your server when you added these lines? You should add the folder like this: `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets')`

Comment: @Waclock Thank you for your comment. I did restart my server, and adding the folders in that way didn't work either unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured it out after remembering that the Rails asset load paths and Sprockets are different systems. Here's what I did:

In `config/initializes/assets.rb`, I added the following lines:

```
# Add additional assets to the asset load path
Rails.application.config.assets.paths += [
  Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets').to_s
]

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [
  Rails.root.join('vendor/assets/javascripts/*').to_s,
  Rails.root.join('vendor/assets/stylesheets/*').to_s
]
```

The first block adds vendor assets to the Rails asset path. This allows me to use vendor assets in view helpers (ex: `image_tag`). The second block allows my vendor JavaScript and CSS to be precompiled with the rest of my assets.

Then, I added the following line to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` above `//= require_tree .`:

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
```

This will automatically add to my application all of the JavaScript files I put into `vendor/assets/javascripts`.

For the Sass, I added the following to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass`:

```
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/*";
```

I added this line before `@import "*";` so that my own application's styles will take preference. This will include all of the vendor Sass files in with my application. Then I renamed all of my vendor `.css` files to use the `.scss` extension.

Now that development is working fine, I was worried about precompilation. I ran `rails assets:precompile` locally, and sure enough, all of my vendor assets were included!